# Problema creando resource routes en Laravel 7

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

Estoy creando rutas para un controlador de tipo *resource* en *Laravel (7.30.0)*.

No quiero usar las rutas *show* y *edit* pero me las esta creando.

He probado con las sintaxis:

```
Route::resource('xxxs', 'XxxsController', ['except' => ['show, edit']]);

Route::resource('xxxs', 'XxxsController')->except(['show, edit']);
```

La última es la que hay en la [doc de Laravel para la versión](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/controllers#restful-partial-resource-routes).

Después de modificar las rutas lanzo el comando:

```
php artisan optimize
```

*que incluye `php artisan route:clear`.*

Al listar las rutas siguen apareciendo *show* y *edit*:

```
php artisan r:l --method=get --name=xxxs
```

> Editado:

También he probado a limpiar la cache:

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

y:

```
php artisan route:cache
php artisan route:clear
```

> Editado:

He probado por si las rutas estuvieran cacheadas en algún lugar desconocido:

```
// Route::resource('xxxs', 'XxxsController')->except(['show, edit']);
Route::resource('xxxs', 'XxxsController')->only(['index']);
```

El listado se hace correctamente en este caso (sólo la ruta con *index*).
Y de nuevo:

```
Route::resource('xxxs', 'XxxsController')->except(['show, edit']);
// Route::resource('xxxs', 'XxxsController')->only(['index']);
```

sigue el problema.

Comment: La consola no te da ningún error al volver a cachear las rutas tras ```php artisan optimize``` ?

Comment: @ItsEdgar94 ningun error, de hecho usaba la sintaxis antigua y no tenía errores, me di cuenta de que tenía las rutas ejecutando test.

Comment: En la misma fuente que referencías, indica que la sintaxis es: `->except['algo', 'otro']`, solo te faltó separarlos como indica la documentación

Answer (score 2):

Pasamos de esto (que no funciona):

```
->except(['show, edit']);
```

a esto otro:

```
->except(['show', 'edit']);
```

Hay que ***poner cada acción en un string independiente*** dentro del array, ***NO un único string*** con todas las acciones, ya sea con el *except* o el *only*.